# How to write a unit testcase for method that uses await in C#

Tags: c#, async-await

I am trying to write a unit testcase for a await method something like this

```
    ExamStatus FakeExamStatus = new ExamStatus();
    ExamDetails FaKeExamDetails = new ExamDetails();

    FakeExamDetails .base64String = "asjdhajshdhasdjhasd";
    FakeExamDetails .eMailID = EmailID;
    FakeExamDetails .fileExtension = FileExtension;
    FakeExamDetails .fileName = FileName;

    ExamResult result = await FakeExamStatus.BlobFileUploadPost(ExamDetails);    

    Assert.AreEqual(result.ReturnMessage, "success", "Not Equal");
```

When I try to pass and get some values it stops the execution at this line? Whether I need to add some wait after the await?

I am using Specflow along with VisualStudio UnitTesting and not the normal unittesting frameworks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declared your test method `async void` (as you seem to imply in the comments), you want to do `async Task` instead. The framework can't await an `async void` method; the only time you want to use `async void` is when you have no other choice (e.g. for certain event handlers).

Comment: MSTest will skip `async void` unit tests and spit out a warning UTA007, but it's not easy to find where the warning is.

Answer (score -1):

```
Async Unit Tests
```

Eg:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task BlobFileUploadAsync()
    {
        bool result = await ExamStatus.BlobFileUploadPost(ExamDetails);
        Assert.AreEqual(true, result);
    }
```

Comment: I have already done that but still there is some issue and it's not getting successfully executed..

Comment: No, don't do `async void`, do `async Task`, the framework can't await `async void`.